# Change the help center privilege page text for "flag posts" to "flag posts and comments"

Tags: feature-request, flags, help-center, privileges-page

[The help center page on privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) says "flag posts", but that privilege also includes the privilege to flag comments. I propose changing the text to say "flag posts and comments".

It would follow to also change the heading in [the "flag posts" privilege page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to say "flag posts and comments" instead.

I'm guessing those changes should be easy. The awkward what-follows-next is: change the page URL from "flag-posts" to "flag-posts-and-comments", which I don't personally care much about whether or not such a change gets made. But if it does, then it would be nice for the old URL to redirect to the new one so the old links don't rot. I say "awkward" because I'll bet this is not a quick and easy change to make, and I'd rather not ask for it if it would prevent the other probably-easy changes from being made more quickly.

Comment: While it is possible to change the page title, I don't see a way for me to change the URL by editing the privilege help page... And changing this title would also necessitate updating the corresponding translations for all 4 international SO sites as well.